# Parse input string with pipes and redirects

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

I have a "pseudo term" wrapper written in bash. it takes input and sends it to a device with the "nc" command. I want it to handle pipes and redirects. This is what I have.

```
while read -ep "${1}> " CMD
do
    [[ ${CMD} =~ '|' ]] && SEP=1
    [[ ${CMD} =~ '>' ]] && SEP=2
    [[ -z ${SEP} ]] && echo "${CMD}"|nc -4u -w1 ${1} 65432 && continue
    CMD1=$(echo ${CMD}|awk -F '[|>]' '{print $1}')
    CMD2=$(echo ${CMD}|awk -F '[|>]' '{print $2}')
    [[ ${SEP} -eq 1 ]] && echo "${CMD1}"|nc -4u -w1 ${1} 65432 | ${CMD2}
    [[ ${SEP} -eq 2 ]] && echo "${CMD1}"|nc -4u -w1 ${1} 65432 > ${CMD2}
done
```

If checks the command variable to see if it contains a pipe or redirect.

If it does not, then send the command, as-is, to nc.

If there is a pipe or redirect, then break the command into two: the part before, and the part after the pipe or redirect.

Send the first part to "nc", and the output to the second part.

It works. But, it can handle only 1 pipe or redirect. I would like it to be able to handle an indeterminate number of pipes and redirects.

Thanks.

Comment: If you could post samples of input and output in your post then it will be more clear for us to help.

Comment: The script will display a prompt with an IP address:

    21.23.43.132>

I can type in various commands, which will be sent to that IP address via the `nc` command:

    21.23.43.132> help

And this will give me some output/.

Supposed I want to do something with this output, such as pipe it to `grep`:

    21.23.43.132> help | grep something

I don't want the script to send "help | grep something" to the `nc` command. I only want the first part sent to `nc`, and anything after the pipe or redirect to be  sent to the unix shell.